# Boot from flash-rom with qemu-system-arm

Tags: embedded, arm, qemu, integrator, rom

Is it possible to emulate boot from flash memory using `qemu-system-arm`? (Using Integrator/CP motherboard)

I'm able to boot using qemu's `-kernel` option, but if I try using an option such as `-pflash`, qemu generates an error telling me that I must use the `-kernel` option. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-kernel` maps the binary file into memory space and boots from it. I believe it's different from flash booting only in that it does not support CFI or similar commands and the memory is writable. Is that important for you? What exactly do you need from "flash boot"?

P.S. the option description says:

`-pflash file    use 'file' as a parallel flash image`

So it seems even if you do that, you still need some bootloader code that would access that flash and load code from it.